# GNU screen lost encoding settings after detached and reattached

Tags: gnu-screen, encoding

I set the defencoding and encoding in the .screenrc,

```
defencoding GBK
encoding GBK GBK
```

After I detached and reattached the session, the encoding settings don't work.

```
screen -r -d -S session
```

How could I make the encoding work?

Thanks for your time.